# Reflecting external Redshift schemas with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am using SQLAlchemy's `automap_base` to build classes for tables in a Redshift Cluster.

Given this code:

```
url = URL.create(
    drivername="redshift+redshift_connector",
    host=host,
    port=port,
    database="prod",
    username=username,
    password=password,
    query={"sslmode": "prefer"}
)
```

I want to create an engine that only connects to `my_schema`. When using the `psycopg2` driver, I can pass in `connect_args` option like this:

```
engine = create_engine(
    url,
    connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path=my_schema'},
    echo=True
)
```

While I can use `psycopg2` to successfully connect to my cluster, `my_schema` is not found. I presume this is because the [metadata is actually stored externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606429/all-redshift-external-schemas-showing-all-the-tables-how-to-limit-visibility-of).

When using the `redshift_connector` dialect, I get a `TypeError` because `options` is not a keyword option for `redshift_connector`.

So the question is how do I reflect tables from an external schema?